# React Map json data and create a dropdown

Tags: json, reactjs

I have json data passed as props from the Redux store, the json has this format:

```
{ 
    "label1.label2.label3": {
        "option1":[
        ],
        "option2": "value",
        "option3": [
        ],
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I need to split the label part and create a nested menu from the data as follows:

```
  label1
       label2
            label3
                option1
                    value of option1
                option2
                    value of option2
                option3
  ...
```

I couldn't figure out how to map into the data, my component code looks like this:

```
  class MyDropdown extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
      //A component dispatches ACTIONS
      this.props.dispatch(fetchDataWithRedux());
    }
    render(){
      const {error, loading, elements} = this.props;
      if (loading){
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
      if (error){
        return <div> Error! {error.message}</div>;
      }
      console.log(this.props.elements); //outputs "undefined"
      return(
        <div>
          {this.props.elements &&     this.props.elements.map(this.createMenu)}
          </div>
      );
    }

    createMenu() {
      return this.props.elements.map((item) => {
        return(

          );
      });
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    elements: state.items,
    loading: state.loading,
    error: state.error
  });
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyDropdown);
```

Comment: How do you build the first three labelX submenus? Does it use a component? Are you always gonna have 3 levels deep of labelX?.

Comment: No, the number of labels per value is arbitrary as well as the options, and I am fetching the data from my API. I only have this component for now.

Comment: To map through the labels you just do `"label1.label2.label3".split(".").map(label => {...});` but without knowing how you do the submenus stuff I can't help much more. You can check the index of the loop function if you always use the options data in the last index of the map.

Comment: Thanks, but creating the menu is always a problem.

Comment: Good examples here on the subject: https://engineering.tripping.com/building-an-recursive-nested-dropdown-component-in-react-b1c883e06ac4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting real close with this. It's pretty tricky to get the nesting right though.

```js
const data = { 
    "label1.label2.label3": {
        "option1":"value1",
        "option2": "value2",
        "option3": "value3"
    },
    "label1.label2.label3.label4": {
        "option1":"value1",
        "option2": "value2"
    },
}

class App extends React.Component {

  createMenu = () => {
  
    const options = Object.keys(data).reduce( (options, key, i) => {
      
      const d = data[key];
      
      let levels = key.split('.').map( (label, i) => {
        return {
          label: label,
          options: []
        };
      });
      
      levels[levels.length -1].options = Object.keys(d).map( option => {
        return {
          label: option,
          value: d[option]
        }
      });
      
      options.push(levels);
      
      return options;
    }, []);
    
    const mapOptions = o => {
    
      let menu = [];
      o.forEach( (option, i) => {
      
        if(!option.options.length) {
          // Nest next option
          menu.push(
            <li>
              {option.label}
            </li>
          );
        }else {
          // display options
          menu.push(
            <li>
              {option.label}
                {option.options.map( nested => {
                  return <li>{nested.label}: {nested.value}</li>
                })}
            </li>
          );
        }
      
      });
   
    return menu;
      
    };
  
    return options.map( option => {
      return mapOptions(option);
    });
    
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.createMenu()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
li li {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_type, text}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Sounds like you are returning the object instead of JSX

Comment: I am sorry but I had a hard time trying to understand the code you wrote as I am new to React, I couldn't solve the error. but I guess the error is there because of the last return of the: <li>{nested.label}: {nested.value}</li> , the value can be multiple?

Comment: yes, if `nested.value` is an array, do: `nested.value.join(', ')`

Comment: It is returning: label1
                             label2
                                  [object, Object], [object, Object] ...

Comment: That means in an array of objects. You'll need to write JSX to display the data you want for those objects.